# Load .htaccess IP from file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I run several wordpress sites on the same server (shared account). I want to only allow myself into the /wp-admin /wp-login.php parts of my sites with IP.

I will FTP in and set my current IP if I need to make changes to my IP(to prevent annoying bots). I do have a static IP, but I'm sure it'll change sometime.

I want to change the .htaccess of my 100 sites to read from 1 file that has the IP. Like a variable.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

My current rules are as follows and it works. Now I want to read the "!^123.123.123.123$" part from a files such as "/myserver/http/public_html/ip", this way when I change it it will go to all .htaccess files on all the servers, changing manually will be tedious when I got 100 sites going. What should I put there to make it us a variable/file that I can modify?

I tried looking at a few sites including this, but it's above my current knowledge:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet/#REMOTE_ADDR

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Comment: If all else fails you can make a PHP script to ftp to each server and upload an updated .htaccess file.

Comment: Wouldn't some dyndns service work too? So you could say `%{REMOTE_ADDR} !chris-home-machine.dyndns.org` in all .htaccess files.